# Why the DataContext returns null value for the out of the ListView Items?

Tags: listview, data-binding, uwp, datacontext, itemssource

I have try to display  the combobox  Items inside the ListViewItems Template by using the below code snippets.And i am try to getting the datacontext of the combobx in combobox loaded event. And datacontext is returns the value only for viewed listViewItems. And it returns the null value for out of the listview items combobox.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonsTest, Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="TieLines">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding Orders}" ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded" Width="250" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

**Questions**
Why is return the DataContext  value as null for out of the view Items in the ListView?
How can get the data-context of out of the view ListViewItems?
Or else if i need to enable any other properties to Binding the ComboBox DataContext in XAML level?

Comment: Could you show the definition for `PersonsTest`, `Orders`, `Numbers`?

Comment: For your question: you are binding the list view datacontext to a property called Orders of an "outer" Datacontext. May be the whole view DataContext. First you must ddefine and assign a DataContext to the view element that contains the listview and then you must create a public property called "Orders" inside this. I don't know why you are doing this trip

Comment: Please, provide also the code where del DataContext of the whole view is set

Answer (score 0):

Just from the names of the data-bound properties it is very likely that you are using the binding incorrectly. When you bind `PersonsTest` to `ItemsSource` of `ListView`, it means that for each person in the `PersonsTest` collection the control takes the `ItemTemplate` and populates it as if the `DataContext` of the template was the specific person. Let's say we are currently instantiating the template for person `P`.

Now when you are using `{Binding Orders}` you are essentially using `p.Orders` property. However, when you set the `DataContext` of the `ComboBox` to `p.Orders`, now the following binding `{Binding Numbers}` becomes **relative** to `p.Orders` as well. So `{Binding Numbers}` basically means `{Binding p.Orders.Numbers}`. I presume this is not what you want, as I would be surprised if the `Orders` would have a property named `Numbers`.

I would expect that you would bind `ComboBox.ItemsSource` to `Orders` and then a `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` and customize it in turn instead of setting the `DataContext`, but as I don't know what your data model is, I am only guessing. The key is that you probably don't need to set the `ComboBox.DataContext` at all and instead just have to correctly set the `ItemsSource` property.